# How can blockchain ensure uniqueness of a digital asset like a photograph?

Tags: visual-cryptography

If I take a picture with my beloved camera, the RAW file can be put into a blockchain, and thus it will have a unique hash.

If that unique hash is ever spotted anywhere we know it's a copy of my photo.

But if someone wants to steal my photo, they could just change a tiny bit of information in the RAW file, and it would result in a new unique hash.

So how can cryptography or the blockchain be used to protect digital assets?

Comment: It seems you are looking for a digital watermarking scheme?

Comment: @Maeher yes, I'll read up on that.

Comment: 1: it can't do that reliably, too many loopholes. 2: besides watermarking, you can publish a fuzzy hash that identifies near matches.